# Boarding Pass v Ticket

Tags: tickets, bookings

I originally booked an Etihad flight through a travel agent, and realised one of the passengers names was spelt wrong.  I got in touch with Etihad and they amended this, and now on my Etihad app this is showing as the correct name.  I was then told to let then travel agents know so they can reissue the ticket, however they are charging £250 for this.  Do I need the ticket if on the Etihad app the name has been changed, will I just need my boarding pass when it becomes available, as this will have the correct spelling?
Thank you

Comment: Did you actually get a paper ticket?

Comment: No haven’t received anything, the flight is at the end of September

Comment: The issue is that the boarding pass most likely won’t be issued if the ticket is not in the right status but rather in some “awaiting payment” state or another…

Comment: Spoke with Etihad and they said they will be able to reissue the tickets 48 hours before the flight for £35, not sure how the travel agents can justify charging £250…

Answer (score 1):

This will largely depend on the terms and conditions of both the travel agent and Etihad. This one of the reasons why it's much preferable to book with the airline directly: there is only one set of terms and conditions in place and it's clear which rules apply.

Etihad is fairly clear about this (https://www.etihad.com/en-us/manage/modification-guide)

> Correct your name
> Title amendments and name corrections due to genuine typing errors (up to three characters) are accepted free of charge.

But of course they also state

> Booked with a travel agent?
> To change or cancel a booking, please contact the travel agent or third party website directly.

So you should

1. Find and read the terms and conditions of your travel agent.
2. Call the travel agent and ask them to correct the spelling. Let them know that Etihad does NOT charge for this service.
3. Hope for the best.

> not sure how the travel agents can justify charging £250

The travel agent can justify everything that's legal and in their terms and conditions that you agreed to when you made the booking. To be fair, most websites clearly state that the name of the passenger must match the name on the travel document exactly.